# Removing all characters other than Armenian, ASCII and Russian letters and some special chars with JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, ecmascript-6

I have some problems with regexp. I'm try to remove all special characters without "- _" it works but only with Latin letters. Can someone help me how to do that.

I need remove all without letters numbers and  "- _".

for example

```
string = "asd;'\;['/\''сдфсдфявэ';щш;э'սդֆսդֆսդֆ«»խլխլ";
```

Comment: Please specify what special characters you need to remove, and build a custom character class for them. Also, consider using [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/).

Comment: i need only letter numbers (unicode) and this two symbols "- _" other things will be replace

Comment: Do you want to include letters such as zenkaku A (Ａ, xFF21)?

Comment: Armenian and Russian letters

Comment: Try [`replace(/[^\wа-яёА-ЯЁ\u0530-\u058F\uFB00-\uFB17-]+/g, '')`](https://jsfiddle.net/rnw8a8kt/1/)

Comment: @Aram, does that work, or do you need to support anything else? Do you have test cases other than the string above?

Comment: oh all works exept this armenian symbols "՛՞։՜;"

Comment: What do you mean? Should they be removed? So, you need to only allow Armenian lower- and uppercase letters? See https://jsfiddle.net/rnw8a8kt/2/, does it work as expected? There is also some apostrophe, half ring and emphasis signs, I do not know if you need to support them. See http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0530.pdf.

Comment: I think it's correct thanks very much, can you write answer that i can vote it :) athanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```js
var s = "՞։՜asd;'\;['/\''сдфсдфявэ';щш;э'սդֆսդֆսդֆ«»խլխլ";
var ret = s.replace(/[^\wа-яёА-ЯЁ\u0561-\u0587\u0531-\u0556-]+/g, '');
document.body.innerHTML = ret;
```

The regex matches multiple occurrences (due to the `g` modifier) of 1 or more (due to the `+` quantifier) characters that are NOT:

- `\w` - ASCII letters, digits or `_`
- `а-яёА-ЯЁ` - Russian letters
- `\u0561-\u0587`  - Armenian capital letters
- `\u0531-\u0556` - Armenian lowercase letters
- `-` - a hyphen.

See [this Unicode reference on Armenian  letter ranges](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0530.pdf) used in the pattern.